# Timelapse with Magic Lantern and Canon 5D mark III

Tags: timelapse, canon-5d-mark-iii, magic-lantern

My hardware timer/remote release was not available today and I recalled Magic Lantern can do timelapses, so I downloaded it and ran it. When ran I can only see some extra stuff in video mode and I couldn't find any ML menus anywhere that would indicate timelapse.

Question is: how do I do a timelapse video on the 5D mark III or at least use ML as a timer.

I'm using most current firmware [1.2.3] and ML for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you've installed ML correctly, the **trash** button activates the Magic Lantern menus.

If you go into the **Shoot** menu, you'll find the **Intervalometer** settings. The **Func** button then lets you modify the intervalometer settings. That will let you take stills at set intervals, which you can then combine into a timelapse video in post processing.